Meaning of "enMesh"
I was reading Stellar English: A Down-to-Earth Guide to Grammar and Style published by Princeton University Press, and there is an expression I can never understand.

She put her left hand palm down on the ­table and  ­gently tapped the ­table several times to signal the  password of her personal device. Suddenly her 3-­D  mesh-­augmented-reality hologram popped up,  projected from her nail-­mons. She enMeshed.  She swiftly navigated the hologram with her right  forefinger.

The author noted that "EnMeshed and nail-­mons are neologisms — new, in­ven­ted words," but never explained its meaning.
I googled, but it wasn't helpful.

Google definition: cause to become entangled in something.

I think it is related to the 3-D mesh reality, but I don't really understand that concept.

I’m voting to close this question because it's about a "self-confessed" neologism, with obviously no associated definition.

In other words, they are invented terms related to some (I assume) imaginary technology - the reader has to guess the meaning.

Is the word spelled with an uppercase M?  If so, it has the form of something that will have been trademarked, like iPhone.

@TimR Yes, it is consistently capitalized.

Technology jargon.
The OP's paragraph has some technological jargon that should be clarified for learners :

Ref. Techtarget.com.
1.A 3D mesh is the structural build of a three-dimensional model consisting of polygons. 3D meshes use reference points in X, Y and Z axes to define shapes with height, width and depth.
2.Augmented reality (AR) is the integration of digital information with the user's environment in real time.
3.A hologram :  a three-dimensional image reproduced from a pattern of interference produced by a split coherent beam of radiation (as from a laser.

For those who are not aware, this technology does not require a monitor. Your icons are projected three-dimensionally in the air and can be accessed by touching them. Now coming to OPs query:

Suddenly her 3-­D mesh-­augmented-reality hologram popped up, projected from her nail-­mons. She enMeshed. She swiftly navigated the hologram with her right forefinger.
The author noted that "EnMeshed and nail-­mons are neologisms — new, in­ven­ted words," but never explained its meaning.

I don't agree that the grammar guide kept the readers in the dark. The word is explained in the next sentence
She enMeshed means she navigated the hologram.
It's not a speculation, but a logical conclusion. The setting clarifies her behaviour. What else could she've done??
